# How to disable entity framework validation for properties not in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using database first to generate my model, and for one of the classes, Foo, I made a separate file with some additional things inside a partial class like this

```
public partial Class Foo 
{
   public typename Bar{get {blahblah}}
}
```

I noticed that when submitting a form to an action, the getter for Bar is entered while loading the action, before any of my code is hit. It seems to be part of some validation by entity framework (it is calling it via reflection. I noticed it called ReflectPropertyDescriptor and MethodInfoInvoke)

Is there a way to turn off validation for Bar in all cases? Or at least at the beginning of the action?

Comment: You should not be passing your entity framework objects to and from controller actions. You should be using view models instead. Also in your example the `Bar` property doesn't have a setter so the model binder will never be able to assign it a value.

Comment: Well I'm passing a viewmodel object to my action that just happens to contain a Foo because a viewmodel for foo would have the exact same properties. 

A bar should never be set so i'm fine with it not having a setter